# OpenGL optimised representation of textures

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d, textures

I have read many places that one should avoid OpenGL textures that are 3 bytes long and should always use 4 bytes bus aligned representations. Keeping that in mind, I have a couple of questions about the glTextImage2D API.

From the documentation, the API signature is:

```
void glTexImage2D(GLenum target,  GLint level,  GLint internalformat,
                  GLsizei width,  GLsizei height,  GLint border,  
                  GLenum format,  GLenum type,  const GLvoid * data);
```

Am I correct in assuming that if I have an RGB image and I want a RGBA representation, it is suffice to specigy the internalformat parameter as GL_RGBA and the format parameter as GL_RGB? Would there be an internal conversion between the formats when generating the texture?

My second question is what if I have grayscale data (so just one channel). Is it ok to represent this as GL_RED or is it also better to have a 4 byte representation for this?

Comment: Any real-world GPU will use a 4 byte alignment per texel for both `GL_RGB` and `GL_RGBA` as `internalFormat`. The recommendation you are referring to just wants to make sure to select the _client side_ `format` which best matches what the GPU will use internally, not switching around the `internalFormat`. You won't gain anything in your scenarion.

Comment: Sorry got slightly confused. So if my data is RGB if I call it with internalformat=GL_RGBA and format=GL_RGB, would I loose any performance?

Comment: when your input is `GL_RGB`, choosing `GL_RGBA` over `GL_RGB` as `internalFormat` will not make a difference. What are you even worried about? The performance of the texture upload or that of sampling from the texture (both will not change in this scenario, but your question is not very clear).

Comment: I was worried about perfomance hit when accessing the texture elements as it will be aligned to a 3 byte boundary rather than 4 byte. However, if I understand you correctly, this will not make any difference.

Comment: The data you have in client memory will be _completely different_ from the internal organisation of the data in GPU memory.   That is not just a linear store of the 2D array  like one might naively assume. The data will be organised in a much more cache-friendly fashion, typically some advanced versions of the general principle of Z-order curves are used, and the specific format is highly implementation-specific. That is also the reason why nicely aligned data formats on the client side should be preferred - the reroder happens in any case, but the alignment makes that process more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, this reordering hit should only happen once when the image is mapped to the texture. All access and subsequent sampling from the texture would not be affected?

Comment: Yes. Using the texture comes with no penalty for RGB vs. RGBA at all. Only the upload has some extra work. And actually, that cost is not as high as it might sound. Typically, the limit is the bus transfer (and multiple data copies). If you care about fast texture upload/streaming, you should use PBOs and be careful to avoid implicit synchronizations.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on PBO. I am looking to share this with CUDA and it seems one can do it with these PBO objects as well. I will have to look at some tutorials on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with the recommendation you found to avoid RGB formats. I can't think of a good reason to avoid RGB textures. Some GPUs support them natively, many other do not. You have two scenarios:

1. The GPU does not support RGB textures. It will use a format that is largely equivalent to RGBA for storage, and ignore the A component during sampling.
2. The GPU supports RGB textures.

In scenario 1, you end up with pretty much the same thing as you get when specifying RGBA as the internal format. In scenario 2, you save 25% of memory (and the corresponding bandwidth) by actually using a RGB internal format.

Therefore, using RGB for the internal format is never worse, and can be better on some systems.

What you have in your code fragment is completely legal in desktop OpenGL. The RGB data you provide will be expanded to RGBA by filling the A component with 1.0. This would not be the case in OpenGL ES, where you can only use a very controlled number of formats for each internal format, which mostly avoids format conversions during `TexImage` and `TexSubImage` operations.

It is generally beneficial to match the internal format and the format/type to avoid conversions. But even that is not as clear cut as it might seem. Say you compare loading RGB data or RGBA data into a texture with an internal RGBA format. Loading RGBA has a clear advantage by not using a format conversion. Since on the other hand the RGB data is smaller, loading it requires less memory bandwidth, and might cause less cache pollution.

Now, the memory bandwidth of modern computer systems is so high that you can't really saturate it with sequential access from a single core. So the option that avoids conversion is likely to be better. But it's going to be very platform and situation dependent. For example, if intermediate copies are needed, the smaller amount of data could win. Particularly if the actual RGB to RGBA expansion can be done as part of a copy performed by the GPU.

One thing I would definitely avoid is doing conversions in your own code. Say you get RGB data from somewhere, and you really do need to load it into a RGBA texture. Drivers have highly optimized code for these conversions, or they might even happen as part of a GPU blit. And it's always going to be better to perform the conversion as part of a copy, compared to your code creating another copy of the data.

Sounds confusing? These kinds of tradeoffs are very common when looking at performance. It's often the case that to get the optimal performance with OpenGL, you need to use a different code path for different GPUs/platforms.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct in assuming that if I have an RGB image and I want a RGBA representation, it is suffice to specigy the internalformat parameter as GL_RGBA and the format parameter as GL_RGB? Would there be an internal conversion between the formats when generating the texture?

This will work, and GL will assign a constant **1.0** to the alpha component for every texel. OpenGL is required to convert *compatible* image data into the GPU's native format during pixel transfer, and this includes things like adding extra image channels, converting from floating-point to fixed-point, swapping bytes for endian differences between CPU and GPU.

For best pixel transfer performance, you need to eliminate all of that extra work that GL would do. That means if you used `GL_RGBA8` as your internal format your data type should be `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` and the pixels should be some variant of `RGBA` (often `GL_BGRA` is the fast path -- the data can be copied straight from CPU to GPU unaltered).

*Storing only 3 components on the CPU side will obviously prevent a direct copy, and will make the driver do more work. Whether this matters really depends on how much and how frequently you transfer pixel data.*

> My second question is what if I have grayscale data (so just one channel). Is it ok to represent this as GL_RED or is it also better to have a 4 byte representation for this?

`GL_RED` is not a representation of your data. That only tells GL which channels the pixel transfer data contains, you have to combine it with a data type (e.g. `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`) to make any sense out of it.

`GL_R8` would be a common internal format for a grayscale image, and that is perfectly fine. The rule of thumb you need to concern yourself with is actually that data sizes needs to be aligned to a power-of-two. So 1-, 2-, 4- and 8-byte image formats are fine. The oddball is 3, which happens when you try to use something like `GL_RGB8` (the driver is going to have to pad that image format for alignment).

Unless you actually need 32-bits worth of gradiation *(4.29 billion shades of gray!)* in your grayscale, stick with either `GL_R8` (256 shades) or `GL_R16` (65536 shades) for internal format.

Comment: By the way, avoid using unsized internal formats. They were removed in GL 3.1 and have always created a bit of ambiguity as to how data was internally represented. For best pixel transfer performance, you need to know the number of bits used internally. So, rather than `GL_RGBA` _(unsized)_, you would use `GL_RGBA8` _(8-bits per-component)_ for your internal format.